# Unexpected substitution of characters

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script that needs to dynamically assemble another script for later execution, however I'm experiencing problems with characters being substituted, specifically any that are escaped such as `\\`, `\t`, `\n` and so-on. While I can work around this issue with variables, it's extremely annoying, especially as the code is provided in segments wrapped as here documents in quoted form, i.e - such that they should not be processed at all.

Even more annoying, on some platforms this substitution seems to extend to other characters as well, such as `\1`, which has been causing havoc with my testing of regular expressions.

Here's a simple example:

```
#!/bin/sh
script=$(cat << 'SCRIPT'
#!/bin/sh
printf '\t%s' "$1"
SCRIPT
)

DIR=$(dirname "$PWD")
echo "$script" > "$DIR/test_script.sh"
```

I would expect this to produce a simple script with the line `printf '\t%s' "$1"`, however instead the line is produced as `printf '    %s' "$1"`, when no substitution is expected.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and ideally, how to prevent this from happening? Like I say, I can work around this with variables for substituted characters, but it's destroying the readability of my script (and is hell to debug).

Comment: Mind telling your version of bash (`bash script.sh`)? It could be a bug.

Comment: @konsolebox I'm not totally sure, as I'm running the script via `sh`, but running `sh -c 'echo $SHELL'` suggests it's a bash shell, while `readlink /bin/sh` reports it as dash. I assume the latter is true, as a lot of the built-ins differ from what I can use in a terminal window. It is useful for me to run in limited environments though, as I'm trying to be as cross-platform as possible (much to the detriment of my sanity =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear your version of `echo` processes some escape characters when you dump the script to a file. `echo` is not well-standardized, since any standard would have conflicted with some previous implementation. Use `printf` instead.

```
#!/bin/sh
script=$(cat << 'SCRIPT'
#!/bin/sh
printf '\t%s' "$1"
SCRIPT
)

DIR=$(dirname "$PWD")
printf "%s\n" "$script" > "$DIR/test_script.sh"
```

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe the answer would be staring me in the face like that, especially after I use `printf` so heavily in other parts of the script! Anyway thanks, I'll go get rid of all the variables I've been using and can hopefully make some more progress before the next incompatibility ;)